# redux-observable to get current location

Tags: react-native, redux, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I'm trying to use react native [Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) to `getCurrentPosition` and then as soon as the position is returned, use [react native geocoder](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder) to use that position to get the location. I'm using [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable) epics to get all of this done.

Here are my two epics:

**location.epic.js**

```
import { updateRegion } from '../map/map.action'
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoder'

export const getCurrentLocationEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(GET_CURRENT_LOCATION)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.fromPromise(Geocoder.geocodePosition(makeSelectLocation()))
        .flatMap((response) => Observable.of(
          getCurrentLocationFulfilled(response)
        ))
        .catch(error => Observable.of(getCurrentLocationRejected(error)))
    )

export const getCurrentPositionEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(GET_CURRENT_POSITION)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => Observable.of(
          updateRegion(position),
          getCurrentLocation(position)
        ),
        error => Observable.of(getCurrentPositionRejected(error)),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
      ).do(x => console.log(x))
    ).do(x => console.log(x))
```

As soon as the app starts, this code executes:

```
class Vepo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => { })
    store.dispatch(fetchCategories())
    store.dispatch(getCurrentPosition())
  }
```

`fetchCategories()` is an action that has an epic too, but that is working. dispatching the `getCurrentPosition()` action runs through the epic above. The only output that I can see is that my reducer handles `getLocationRejected()` as it console logs this:

```
there was an issue getting your current location:  Error: invalid position: {lat, lng} required
    at Object.geocodePosition (geocoder.js:15)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (location.epic.js:17)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:120)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:110)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:88)
    at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
    at Object.dispatch (createEpicMiddleware.js:72)
    at Object.dispatch (devTools.js:313)
```

Here is my reducer:

```
const searchPage = (
  initialLocationState = initialState.get('searchForm').get('location'),
  action: Object): string => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CURRENT_LOCATION_FULFILLED: {
      return action.payload
    }
    case GET_CURRENT_LOCATION_REJECTED: {
      console.log('there was an issue getting your current location: ', 
        action.payload)
      return initialLocationState
    }
    case GET_CURRENT_POSITION_REJECTED: {
      console.log('there was an issue getting your current position: ', 
        action.payload)
      return initialLocationState
    }
    default:
      return initialLocationState
  }
}
```

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong? My attempt to debug by adding `.do(x => console.log(x))` does nothing, nothing is logged to the console. `updateRegion()` never does fire off because that dispatches an action and the reducer `UPDATE_REGION` never executes. But the execution must make it into the success case of `getCurrentPosition()` eg:

```
(position) => Observable.of(
              updateRegion(position),
              getCurrentLocation(position)
            ),
```

must execute because the `getCurrentLocation(position)` does get dispatched.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the react-native APIs but it appears you're returning the result of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` in the `mergeMap`--but `mergeMap` expects an Observable to be returned? If that is true, this should produce an error, **if** it ever reaches that point. Doesn't `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` not return anything and instead uses callbacks? I would comment out all your catches and make sure you're not swallowing other errors, then try to isolate each step; test each epic individually until you find which one is the cause and then further isolate.

Comment: @jayphelps yeah you're correct. I don't think anything really happens. I don't think it reaches the point to produce an error, not even in getPositionEpic. I get the same result (console log saying getLocation was rejected) no matter what I do. I just don't know how to debug the getPositionEpic but I will try isolating the steps tonight. Thanks.

Comment: @jayphelps What would be your technique for using an epic on a function which takes a callback function? `getCurrentPosition()` takes a callback and the callback handles the payload. Basically if you remove `Observable.of(` from inside `getCurrentPosition()`, that's how `getCurrentPosition()` is correctly used - and has been working for me without redux-observable. However I see a case using for redux-observable for dispatching the `GET_CURRENT_LOCATION` action when `getCurrentPosition()` recieves the payload - and I want to use it for that reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What would be your technique for using an epic on a function which takes a callback function? getCurrentPosition() takes a callback and the callback handles the payload. Basically if you remove Observable.of( from inside getCurrentPosition(), that's how getCurrentPosition() is correctly used - and has been working for me without redux-observable.

Wrapping anything in a custom Observable is fairly simple, very similar to creating a Promise except Observables are lazy--this is important to understand! [RxJS Docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observable)

In the case of geolocation, there are two main APIs, `getCurrentPosition` and [`watchPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition). They have identical semantics except that `watchPosition` will call your success callback every time the location changes, not just a single time. Let's use that one since it's natural to model it as a stream/Observable and most flexible.

```
function geolocationObservable(options) {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    // This function is called when someone subscribes.

    const id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        observer.next(position);
      },
      error => {
        observer.error(error);
      },
      options
    );

    // Our teardown function. Will be called if they unsubscribe
    return () => {
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
    };
  });
}

geolocationObservable({ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 })
  .subscribe(
    position => console.log(position),
    e => console.error(e)
  );
  // will log every time your location changes, until you unsubscribe
```

Since it's now an Observable, if you only want the current location you can just do `.take(1)`.

So using it inside your epic might be like this

```
// If you want, you could also use .share() to share a single
// underlying `watchPosition` subscription aka multicast, but
// that's outside the scope of the question so I don't include it
const currentPosition$ = geolocationObservable({
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 20000,
  maximumAge: 1000
});

export const getCurrentPositionEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(GET_CURRENT_POSITION)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      currentPosition$
        .take(1) // <----------------------------- only the current position
        .mergeMap(position => Observable.of(
          updateRegion(position),
          getCurrentLocation(position)
        ))
        .catch(error => Observable.of(
          getCurrentPositionRejected(error)
        ))
    );
```

---

As a side note, you might not need to dispatch both `updateRegion()` and `getCurrentLocation()`. Could your reducers just listen for a single action instead, since they both seem to be signalling the same intent?